# Сравнение двух массивов JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Разрабатываю приложение типа викторины с вопросами. Не могу решить задачу или решаю ее очень криво.
Есть два массива:

Ответы пользователя:

```
0:{questionId: "1", answerId: "1"}
1:{questionId: "2", answerId: "4"}
2:{questionId: "2", answerId: "6"}
3:{questionId: "3", answerId: "8"}
```

И правильные ответы:

```
0:{questionId: "1", answerId: "3"}
1:{questionId: "2", answerId: "4"}
2:{questionId: "2", answerId: "6"}
3:{questionId: "3", answerId: "7"}
```

Мне нужно сравнить два массива и получить нечто подобное:

```
0:{questionId: "1", result: false} \\ пользователь дал не правильный ответ
1:{questionId: "2", result: true}  \\ пользователь дал правильный ответ по 
                                      второму вопросу, в нем два варианта 
                                      ответа оба совпали. Иначе false если 
                                      один из ответов не верен 
2:{questionId: "3", result: false} \\ пользователь дал не правильный ответ
```

Не получается у меня никак этот сделать. Как решить эту задачу?

Моё решение:

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

            let userAnswers = [];
            let answers = [];

            $('#checkResultBtn').click(function () {
                $('input:checked', '.card-body').each(function () {
                    userAnswers.push({
                        questionId: $(this).attr('name'),
                        answerId: $(this).val()
                    });
                });
                console.log(userAnswers);
                console.log(answers);
                diff(userAnswers, answers);


            });
            function diff(userAnswers, answers) {
                userAnswers.forEach(function (userAns) {
                    answers.forEach(function (ans) {
                        if (userAns['questionId'] == ans['questionId']) {
                            if (userAns['answerId'] == ans['answerId'])
                                console.log(true)                          
                            else
                                console.log(false)
                        }

                    });


                });

            }

            @foreach(var answers in Model){

                var answersList = answers.Answers.Where(x => x.Answer == 1);

                   foreach(var answer in @answersList)
                   {
                    <text>
                    answers.push({
                        questionId: '@answer.QuestionId',
                          answerId: '@answer.Id'
                                });

                    </text>
                   }

            }




            });



</script>
}
```

https://pastebin.com/B2K5z9UX

P. S.
Стоит учесть, что массив со стороны пользователя может по длине не совпадать с массивом правильных ответов.
Пользователь может не ответить на вопрос вообще.

Comment: Как Вы её решили? Или решаете.

Comment: Пока очень плохо, можно сказать, что никак. Сравниваю их в цикле.

Comment: Выложите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы можете менять структуру генерации этих структур? Они сейчас неправильны, нужно иначе делать.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/B2K5z9UX

Comment: @Other Можете подсказать, почему структура генерации данных не правильна?  База на Sqlite

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78016/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-other).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var ans = [
  {questionId: "1", answerId: "1"},
  {questionId: "2", answerId: "4"},
  {questionId: "2", answerId: "6"},
  {questionId: "3", answerId: "8"},
];

var keys = [
  {questionId: "1", answerId: "3"},
  {questionId: "2", answerId: "4"},
  {questionId: "2", answerId: "6"},
  {questionId: "3", answerId: "7"},
];

var keys2 = Object.create(null);

for (var x of keys) {
  (keys2[x.questionId] = keys2[x.questionId] || []).push(x.answerId);
}

for (var x of Object.keys(keys2)) {
  keys2[x].sort();
}

var ans2 = Object.create(null);
var res = [];

for (var x of ans) {
  (ans2[x.questionId] = ans2[x.questionId] || []).push(x.answerId);
}

for (var x of Object.keys(ans2)) {
  res.push({questionId: x, result: ans2[x].sort() + '' == keys2[x]});
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```